# Knowing programmatically if cell data is disabled for the app for iOS

Tags: ios, cell

My app needs to know if the application can use cellular data when running. Is there a way programmatically to know before hand if cellular data is enabled for the application?

Comment: I see reachability to see if there is a internet connection. that is not what I want, if my internet connection is on wifi, I want to know if a internet route can be created using Cell. This will tell me if data access vial Cell is enabled or not.